# Custom query with meta_key not working fine

Tags: wp-query

I'm making the following query in order to get all the posts sorted by a meta key (wpcf-estado in this case) but it returns the items in no order:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array( 
                        'post_type' => 'proyectos',
                        'posts_per_page' => 8,
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'meta_key' => 'wpcf-estado',
                        //'meta_value' => 'a',                                      
        );
```

If I uncomment the 'meta_value' parameter, I end up succesfully getting only the posts containing 'a' as wpcf-estado.

The possible values of wpcf-estado are: a, b or c.

I tried several things but didn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Your first line implies you're using `query_posts` or a replacement `WP_Query`, consider using a `pre_get_posts` filter instead, it should make the page ~2x as fast, and allow you to remove all the pagination fixing code

Comment: Also, if you're trying to categorise by type A B or C, a taxonomy with terms A B and C would be more performant than post meta

Comment: Can you try adding `'meta_type' => 'char'`?

Comment: Tried with no success.

Answer (score 1):

@Rod0n WP version 4.2 included the number of improvements in [WP_QUERY](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) particularly when use the 'meta_query' parameter. Also, check the W[P_QUERY Class Refernece](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

```
$args = array( 
         'post_type' => 'proyectos' ,
         'posts_per_page' => 8 , 
         'paged' => $paged,
         'orderby' => array(
           'meta_value' => 'DESC'
          ), 
         'meta_query' => array(
           array(
             'key' => 'wpcf-estado',
             'compare' => 'EXISTS',
          ),
       ),
    );
```

Hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` ?

Even better I think and shothand

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'proyectos',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby'  => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-estado'
    //'meta_value' => 'a',                                      
);
```